# How to add JComboBox on JTable cell on MouseClick and based on other cells values from the Same JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, mouseevent, jcombobox, tablecolumn

JTable:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDorA.jpg]

I have created an **JTable** in **NetBeans** in which i am bring values from **database** in certain columns like as shown in **image** i am bringing values for **TESTNAME,UNITS,SPECIFICRANGE** columns but the second column **OBSERVED VALUE** i have kept empty for **user input**,the user input is such that whenever the user clicks on the cell in front of **Color** he should get an **JComboBox** in the second columns cell i mean the cell in front of the **Color** on MouseEvent and for other cells i am using **editCellAt()**
In Order to accompalish this i have written the below code and when i click on the cell in front of color i am getting **JComboBox** also when i click on other cells i am getting the **JComboBox** but i need to get the **editCellAt()** functionality

I think **DefaultCellEditor** is getting fixed for whole column but i need it only for particular cell on **MouseClick**

```
if(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0).toString().equals("Color"))
{
   TableColumn colorColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
   JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
   comboBox.addItem("Red");
   comboBox.addItem("Greyish");
   comboBox.addItem("Yellow");
   colorColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
}               
else
{
   table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how to dynamically return a custom editor:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<String[]> editorData = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editorData to be used for each row

        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" } );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( editorData.get(row));
                    return new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your case you need to modify the `getCellEditor(...)` method to return then combo box based in the data in column 0 of the TableModel, otherwise return the default editor. You may also need to override to `editCellAt(...)` method to only make the cell editable based on the data in column 0.

Comment: Hi,.. Since i have used JTable from the netbeans so i added getCellEditor() method by customizing the code but i do not get any combobox also what do i need to code in if() block i mean how do i need to call the Overridden getCellEditor Method

Comment: Hi,.. I have tried this i am not successfull,.. I need to get JComboBox on Mouse Event I m not getting how i need to do it,. Please Help.

Comment: Hi, @camickr the example which you given comes when i google around but how this needs to implemented for single cell,.... I mean how to do it in Mouse Event ,.....

Comment: @a You don't use a MouseEvent. JTable handles the MouseEvent and invokes the editor. I gave you working code and suggested you just need a simple change to the if statement. I can't guess how you modified this working code so I can't help. The point is for you do modify this code with a simple change to the if statement and then when you understand how this works you apply change to your real code.